# ElasticSearch : Exception in thread "main" NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I am trying to use the Java Bulk API for creating the documents in ElasticSearch. I am using a JSON file as the bulk input. When I execute, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: []]
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:280)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:197)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:55)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:272)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:347)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:85)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:59)
at bulkApi.test.App.main(App.java:92)
```

This is the java code.

```
package bulkApi.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequestBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.TransportAddress;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;


/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */


public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, ParseException
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
     // configuration setting

        Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
        .put("cluster.name", "test-cluster").build();
        TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build();

        String hostname = "localhost";
        int port = 9300;
        client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(hostname),port));
        // bulk API
        BulkRequestBuilder bulkBuilder = client.prepareBulk();

        long bulkBuilderLength = 0;
        String readLine = "";
        String index = "testindex";
        String type = "testtype";
        String _id = null;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("/home/nilesh/Shiney/Learn/elasticSearch/ES/test/parseAccount.json"))));
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        while((readLine = br.readLine()) != null){
        // it will skip the metadata line which is supported by bulk insert format
            if (readLine.startsWith("{\"index")){
                continue;
            }
            else {
                Object json = parser.parse(readLine);
                if(((JSONObject)json).get("account_number")!=null){
                    _id = String.valueOf(((JSONObject)json).get("account_number"));
                    System.out.println(_id);
                }

            //_id is unique field in elasticsearch
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) json;
            bulkBuilder.add(client.prepareIndex(index, type, String.valueOf(_id)).setSource(jsonObject));
            bulkBuilderLength++;

            try {
                if(bulkBuilderLength % 100== 0){
                    System.out.println("##### " + bulkBuilderLength + "data indexed.");
                    BulkResponse bulkRes = bulkBuilder.execute().actionGet();
                if(bulkRes.hasFailures()){
                    System.out.println("##### Bulk Request failure with error: " +                                              bulkRes.buildFailureMessage());
                        }
                    bulkBuilder = client.prepareBulk();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
        br.close();

        if(bulkBuilder.numberOfActions() > 0){
            System.out.println("##### " + bulkBuilderLength + " data indexed.");
            BulkResponse bulkRes = bulkBuilder.execute().actionGet();
            if(bulkRes.hasFailures()){
                System.out.println("##### Bulk Request failure with error: " + bulkRes.buildFailureMessage());
            }
            bulkBuilder = client.prepareBulk();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check:

1. Check that your cluster name is same as the one defined in
   elastic.yml
2. Try creating the index with the index name
   ('testindex' in your case) with PUT api from any REST Client
   (ex:AdvancedRestClient) http://localhost:9200/testindex (Your
   request has to be successful i.e status code==200 )

Run your program after you create the index with the above PUT request.